# Eevee world AO disappears behind other objects

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows, ambient-occlusion

I have a project, where I need a big area evenly lit. I imagine a big room with a lot of top lights but the shadows just look like 20 independent hard shadows on top of each other and I can't get it to one smooth shadow.
So I use a HDRI. The Problem there is that this wont cast shadows, or I don't know how.
If there is a way to do that in eevee, this would be perfect.
So I tried use global Ambient Occlusion, which works good, but...
When ever an object passes in front of the AO-shadow, the shadow disappears.

[image: 1]
the shadow of the table is missing on the left and in the hole of the cube

And I can't find anything about this. I use 2.83 but in 2.91 is the same problem.
I also tried Irradiance Volume but that won't work for all of the moving parts I want to add.
Does someone know what I am missing, or what I could do to lighten such a scene?

Here is the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R_FhbiHXbNqBV8N_tpuZ1xdgNaquO7P2/view?usp=sharing). I added the cubes as placeholders.

Comment: Seems like a limitation: https://developer.blender.org/T60072

Comment: So SSAO just don't work with somthing else in front? Ist isn't a question of distance or clipping...
But even if I use it for a relative big distance, it's kinda hard to think this usually isn't a Problem.
How else would I get smooth shadows in this kind of setting?